# Add that the resulting JSX Element has a required property (Typescript with React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a function that returns a JSX element to me and I need the resulting component to have 100% of the onClick property.

I tried:

```
export interface MyJSX extends JSX.Element{
    onClick(value: string): void
}
```

My function type:

```
customRenderer(onClick: () => void): MyJSX
```

My function:

```
const customRenderer = (onClick: () => void) : MyJSX => {
    return (
       <div onClick={() => onClick()}>
    
       </div>
    )
}
```

And that returns an error `property onClick is missing on type Element but required in MyJSX`

Some way to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

interface MyComponentProps {
  onClick: () => void;
}

const customRenderer: FC<MyComponentProps> = ({ onClick }) => {
    return (
       <div onClick={() => onClick()}>
    
       </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: This forces to pass onClick as properties, but not to use it

Comment: Maybe you should create a new component, as a wrapper around div, which will have required `onClick` property and then use it...

Comment: Yeah, that is what i actually did but I wanna know how resolve the problem for improve